# Multiple events getting created on creating event in Teams with 100 members using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, azure-functions

I am creating teams event using Graph API in my Azure function. For 10-30 members, I am able to create an event in MS Teams using Graph. It is sending an email notification also to the members for Join meeting.
When I tried with 50-100 members, multiple events getting created and multiple email notification also sending to each member.
Is there any member limitation or my code issue?

```
    DateTime dStartDate = DateTime.Parse(session.SessionStartDateTime);
    DateTime dEndDate = DateTime.Parse(session.SessionEndDateTime);

    List<Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek> dayOfWeeks = new List<Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek>();
    dayOfWeeks.Add(Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek.Monday);
    dayOfWeeks.Add(Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek.Tuesday);

         Event @event = new Event
                    {
                        Subject = "Test Meeting",
                        Body = new ItemBody
                        {
                            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                            Content = "Online Meeting - Test Meeting"


   },
                    Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                    {
                        DateTime = session.StartDateStartTime,
                        TimeZone = "Eastern Standard Time"
                    },
                    End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                    {
                        DateTime = session.StartDateEndTime,
                        TimeZone = "Eastern Standard Time"
                    },
                    Location = new Location
                    {
                        DisplayName = "Online"
                    },
                    Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
            {
                Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                {
                    Type = Weekly,
                    Interval = 1,
                    DaysOfWeek = dayOfWeeks
                },
                Range = new RecurrenceRange
                {
                    Type = EndDate,
                    StartDate = new Date(dStartDate.Year, dStartDate.Month, dStartDate.Day),
                    EndDate = new Date(dEndDate.Year, dEndDate.Month, dEndDate.Day)
                }
            };
                    IsOnlineMeeting = true,
                    OnlineMeetingProvider = "TeamsForBusiness"
                };

                List<Attendee> attendees = new List<Attendee>();

                if (session?.instructors?.Count > 0)
                {
                    session.instructors.ForEach(s =>
                    {
                        attendees.Add(new Attendee
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = s.Email,
                                Name = s.Name
                            },
                            Type = AttendeeType.Required
                        });
                    });
                }

                if (session?.shoppers?.Count > 0)
                {
                    session.shoppers.ForEach(s =>
                    {
                            attendees.Add(new Attendee
                            {
                                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                                {
                                    Address = s.Email,
                                    Name = s.Name
                                },
                                Type = AttendeeType.Required
                            });
                    });
                }
                @event.Attendees = attendees;

GraphServiceClient graph = GetAuthenticatedClient(session.tenantADInformation);
                Event @event = PrepareEvent(session);
                string Email = session.instructors.FirstOrDefault()?.Email;
                var Event = await graph.Users[Email].Events
                   .Request()
                   .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + session.TenantTimeZone + "\"")
                   .AddAsync(@event);
```

If it is 50-100 attendees then my Event is having Event.IsOnlineMeeting as false(even though I have set that to true) and  Event.OnlineMeeting is coming as null.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think exist any limitation in this case. Since the api allows us to create the event for the members, we can request it although there are many members. The only factor which may limit it is the max number of members in teams is 500. In addition to this, I think the api and the code can work fine.